# Cannot read property 'subscribeToMore' of undefined in Apollo

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a subscription in Apollo client, but every time I save my component, which causes a refresh, I get this error:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
const QUERY = gql`
  {
    getEventsSection(id: "trending") {
      _id,
      events 
    }
  }
`;

const SUBSCRIPTION = gql`
    subscription {
      getEventsSection(id: "trending") {
        _id,
        events 
      }
    }
`;
    const [state, setState] = useState(null);
        const { loading, error, data, subscribeToMore } = useQuery(QUERY);

        useEffect(() => {
            const unsubscribe = subscribeToMore({
                document: SUBSCRIPTION,
                updateQuery: (prev, {subscriptionData}) => {
                    console.log(subscriptionData);
                }
            });
            return () => unsubscribe();
        }, [data])
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to return anything in `updateQuery` callback.

As [per docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/#subscribetomore)

> Note that the updateQuery callback must return an object of the same shape as the initial query data, otherwise the new data won't be merged. Here the new comment is pushed in the comments list of the entry:

Also [remove unsubscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60515463/how-to-unsubscribe-with-usequery-and-subscribetomore) in useEffect

Comment: I tried with ```const {data} = subscriptionData; return Object.assign({}, prev, data);``` and I'm still getting the error. It seems that ```subscribeToMore``` is sometimes undefined on a component refresh. The first time the component load, the subscription works, but I can't for example save the file, which causes a component reload. Im also returning the same shape of the data query object.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was causing this?